# How to handle divergent streams when recovering from error in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I have an rx stream that may produce an error in an early operator. If this error happens I'm able to recover, but the recovery "path" no longer emits the same type items as the "happy path". What is the best way to handle this situation?

As an example. Let's say my first `map` normally emits an `Integer`. It also sometimes throws `MyException`. I can recover from this error, but I start down a new path that emits `MyObject` not an `Integer`.

```
public void main() {
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
              .map(integer -> { // double
                  if (integer == 3) {
                      throw new MyException();
                  }
                  return integer * 2;
              })
              .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Integer>>() {
                  @Override
                  public Observable<? extends Integer> call(Throwable throwable) {
                      if (throwable instanceof MyException) {
                          // recover from MyException,
                          // but I start down a new path that doesn't emit an Integer
                          return Observable.just(true)
                                           .map((Func1<Boolean, MyObject>) aBoolean -> new MyObject());
                      } else { // just propagate all other errors
                          return Observable.error(throwable);
                      }
                  }
              })
              .map(integer -> "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ " + integer.toString()) // table flip
              .subscribe(
                      System.out::println, // on next
                      throwable -> {
                          if (throwable instanceof MyException) {
                              // not possible, since I recovered from MyException
                          }
                          System.out.println("error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                      },
                      () -> System.out.println("stream completed"));
}

private class MyException extends RuntimeException {}
private class MyObject {}
```

Comment: You can't handle items with two different types at once.

Comment: You can use groupBy to filter the result and add different subscriber to it.

Comment: @DeanXu yeah that's my point =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`groupBy`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#groupBy(rx.functions.Func1)) operator might help in this case.  Check out this answer and see if it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120775/1830141

Answer (score 1):

You could move the second mapping before the `onErrorResumeNext()` call. If you use the common super-type of the mapping and the *next* value (in your example `Object`), you can propagate both values to the subscriber and handle it correctly there.

```
Observable
    .<Integer>just(...)
    .<Integer>map(...)
    .<Object>map(...)
    .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Object>>() {
         @Override
         public Observable<? extends Integer> call(Throwable throwable) {
             if (throwable instanceof MyException) {
                 return Observable.just(true)
                            .<MyObject>map(aBoolean -> new MyObject());
             } else {
                 return Observable.error(throwable);
             }
         }
     })
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: so then my `subscribe(onNext(Object object) )` method is just expecting an `Object`? It may be a `String` if all goes well, or `MyObject` if I recover from an error? And then i just switch off of the object's type?

Comment: That was the idea. Or you use the more fancy `groupBy` operator mentioned here already.